# Atomic update using complex multi-field expressions in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I've been trying to figure out how to update a field in MongoDB using a complex expression.  The purpose of this is to atomically update the average voter score of a post when a user adds a vote, without having to store every vote and re-evaluate them every time.

The equation I am using is this:

```
average = (size * average + value) / (size + 1);
```

And I converted this to what I thought was a MongoDB update expression, which SHOULD set the average and the size in a single atomic expression:

```
db.Post.update({"_id": id}, 
{ 
    $set: { 
        'average' : { 
            '$divide' : [ 
                { 
                    '$add' : [ 
                        { '$multiply' : [ 'size' , 'average' ] } , 
                        value 
                    ] 
                } , 
                { '$add' : [ 'size' , 1 ] } 
            ] 
        } , 
        'size' : { 
            '$add' : [ 'size' , 1 ] 
        } ,
        'total' : {
            '$add' : [ 'total' , value ]
        }
    } 
})
```

Apparently though, I don't know what I'm doing, because I got back the error:

```
error: "Cast to Number failed for value \"{ '$add': [ 'total', 0.25 ] }\" at path \"total\""
```

I tried searching around a bit more and adding dollar signs to the field names since apparently the $set syntax requires that, but that didn't help either, I got the same error.  Now I'm stuck.  Is there any way to convert a complex expression like this to a single MongoDB update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using agggregate operators, with updates operators, we can't do that, if we use aggregate operators we should use an aggregate pipeline update but this requires MongoDB >=4.2.

Query (its like your query small modifications,replace your `{"$set" ...}`
with the bellow pipeline (dont forget the []))

```js
db.Post.update({"_id": id}, 
[ {
  "$set" : {
    "average" : {
      "$divide" : [ {
        "$add" : [ {
          "$multiply" : [ "$size", "$average" ]
        }, YOUR_VALUE_VARIABLE ]
      }, {
        "$add" : [ "$size", 1 ]
      } ]
    },
    "size" : {
      "$add" : [ "$size", 1 ]
    }
  }
}])
```

Comment: I'm confused.  I did this before (with the $ signs before the fields) but it didn't help.  How would I use this to update a post with a given id?  Using Mongoose preferably.

Comment: i dont use mongoose, but you had to replace only the `$set` part, i re-edit now try that if you can

Comment: Ah, I see...putting it in [] seems to work.